# Do Scroll function in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

In the Kivy app I am working on, I have just one screen with all of the app's content including multiple Labels and images, etc contained within a ScrollView. I also have an MDNavigationDrawer as well managing all the buttons that I intend to have automatically scroll to the intended Label within the original ScrollView. However, I am having difficulties finding any reasonable way to perform this function.

```
Screen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            pos_hint: {"top":1}
            title: "Navigation"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        ScrollView:
            id: MyScrollView

            GridLayout:
                id: MyGridLayout
                cols:1
                size_hint_y:None
                size_hint:1,None
                height:self.minimum_height

                Image:
                    name:"HeaderImage1"
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba:(1,1,1,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    source:"anderson_header.png"

               Label:
                    name: 'UniversalPatientCareL1'
                    id: 'UniversalPatientCareL1'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba:(0,0,0,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    text_size:self.width,None
                    text:'Universal Patient Care'
                    font_size:'52sp''

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id:nav_drawer
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Image:
                name:"HeaderImage1"
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(1,1,1,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos:self.pos
                        size:self.size
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                source:"anderson_header.png"

            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    size_hint_y:None
                    size_hint:1,None
                    height:self.minimum_height

                    Label:
                        name:"GeneralCareLabel"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba:(0,0,0,1)
                            Rectangle:
                                pos:self.pos
                                size:self.size
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        text_size:self.width,None
                        text:'General Protocols'
                        font_size:'30sp'

                    Button:
                        name:"Universal"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba:(21/255.0,113/255.0,146/255.0,1)
                            Rectangle:
                                pos:self.pos
                                size:self.size
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        text_size:self.width,None
                        text:'Universal Patient Care'
                        font_size:'20sp'
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        on_release:UniversalPatientCareH1.y / 
                       MyScrollView.height
```

If I wanted to have the "Universal" button cause the ScrollView to automatically scroll to the UniversalPatientCareL1 label, any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Try using the [scroll_to()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_to) method